# Is every action from an amenable group amenable on a unital $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: c-star-algebras

Is every action from an amenable group amenable on a unital $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: It would help if you reminded people what you mean by an amenable action on a $C^*$-algebra, and made more precise the quantifiers in your question.

Comment: Ah, so you were asking if each (discrete?) amenable group has an amenable action on some unital C*-algebra. This seems to be answered below.

Comment: Yes I mente discrete group. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. It follows from Theorem 3.3 of [1] and the fact that the trivial action of an amenable group on $\mathbb{C}$ is amenable.  More modern reference is [2] (in particular Section 4.3).

[1] C. Anantharaman-Delaroche. Systèmes dynamiques non commutatifs et moyennabilité. Math. Ann., 279(2):297–315, 1987.

[2] N. P. Brown and N. Ozawa. C*-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations, volume 88 of Graduate Studies in Mathematics. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2008.

Comment: I think this is more easier to see if we use definition in [2] Section 4.3. 